# Is there a easy-to-install distribution with all the necessary tools to compile (make, autotools, etc)?

Tags: virtual-machine, make

I'm working on a workstation without root privileges.
Since I need some tools I cannot install directly, I wish to put them in a vm.
The problem is, I cannot connect to the repositories from the vm (proxyblocked, I can't do anything about it), so I'm looking for a distribution which has make, autotools, etc... so I can directly compile the tools I need using the sources.
I never had to install Linux without network connection, so I don't know what packages come with naked iso.

I tried Lubuntu 14.10 amd64, but make was not installed.
Thanks in advance,

EDIT :
VMware is already installed, and I don't need root to create a new vm in it. I already installed successfully Lubuntu inside the vm, but I dont have make :

```
nihl@nihl-virtual-machine:~/packages/autoconf-2.69$ make
The program 'make' can be found in the following packages:
 * make
 * make-guile
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
nihl@nihl-virtual-machine:~/packages/autoconf-2.69$ sudo apt-get install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate
nihl@nihl-virtual-machine:~/packages/autoconf-2.69$
```

(I already tried apt-get update, and it can't connect)

Comment: To set up and run a VM, you need root as well, I think. And any distribution should have the basic tools you need. Maybe you need to use a big enough installation disk. Lubuntu, for example, would certainly have everything you need.

Comment: VMware is already installed, I don't need root to create a new vm in it. In fact I already installed successfully Lubuntu inside the vm, but I dont have make.
And I am not sure I understand what you mean by "a big enough installation disk" ? There is various size of iso ?

Comment: Sure there are. These days Ubuntu/Debian require multiple DVDs for the full installation. What media did you try installing from? For basic dev tools a single DVD (the first) should be enough though.

Comment: @Nihl Is the problem with apt itself or could it be a general connectivity issue?

Comment: I directly went to Lubuntu website, which redirect me here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu ; so far I did not see anything but the usual ~700MB cd image.

Comment: If bandwidth is not the issue, download the Debian DVD image and use that. See https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/. Or just google "Debian DVD". It will give you some hits. Jessie/testing is releasing this weekend, so you probably want to install that, unless you have some compelling reason not to. However, looking again at your question, I recommend you try to fix your networking issue first. You should post this as a separate question though.

Comment: If you have questions, you can hop into the U&L chat room. It looks like you have enough rep for that. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian provides CD/DVD images that you can use as package installation sources after the OS installation: http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.8.0/amd64/iso-dvd/

Mind you that the link is for the (still) current stable release, Wheezy. The next stable release, Jessie, is expected within a few days so if you're not pressed for time you might wish to wait for a couple of days or download images for the testing branch to get newer packages.